# sqlalchemy: insert pandas DataFrame into two SQL tables

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, sqlalchemy

**Problem:**
I got a table as a pandas DataFrame object. The columns are `'type', 'url', 'user-id' and 'user-name'`. I want to insert this table into a SQLite database with the following tables:

```
table urls
    url PRIMARY KEY
    type
    user-id

table users
    user-id
    user-name
```

There shall be a one-to-many relationship from users to urls.

**My attempt**:
I think of an algorithm like:

```py
for row in df:
    # insert into urls table

    # check if the user-id exists already in users

    # if not: insert into users
```

**Question 1:** Do you agree with my algorithm or is there anything much simpler?

Up to now, I don't have much experience using sqlalchemy.

**Question 2:** Would you implement that using the sqlalchemy ORM or the expression language? How to automatically delete all urls, if a user is deleted?

Comment: For question one can I ask if your attempt works or not?

Comment: pandas also has a function called `to_sql` this will be useful probably: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: @Hadus yes it works but it does not feel elegant at all. The pandas `to_sql` function does not work for inserting into  2 tables at the same time does it?

Comment: Any luck on this?